# getUseLinkForAsLowAs boolen

Tags: magento2, price

I need to make getUseLinkForAsLowAs false. How can I do it?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify layout for this

Create layout update (for example `view/base/layout/default.xml` in your module)
with following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.price.render.default">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="use_link_for_as_low_as" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

You can modify options separately for each product type or page type